# execute result of select statement

Tags: sql-server, executequery

How can I execute the results of my select query. The query below gives me some SQL statements back as result. I want to execute does statements, how to do this? All this is executed in SQL Sever Management Studio.

Query:

```
SELECT 'UPDATE Rolecopy SET PartofFT = ''' + R2.PlayedbyOT + ''', OriginalOT = ''' + R.PlayedbyOT + ''' WHERE RoleNo = ' + CAST(R.RoleNo AS VARCHAR) + CHAR(13)
FROM Role R INNER JOIN Role R2
ON R.PartofFT = R2.PartofFT AND R.RoleNo <> R2.RoleNo
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT PG.RoleNo
    FROM V_PurposeGrouping PG
    WHERE R.PartofFT = PG.PartofFT
    AND R.RoleNo <> PG.RoleNo
)
```

Result:

```
UPDATE Rolecopy SET PartofFT = 'Student', OriginalOT = 'Teacher' WHERE RoleNo = 5.00
UPDATE Rolecopy SET PartofFT = 'Project', OriginalOT = 'Teacher' WHERE RoleNo = 8.00
UPDATE Rolecopy SET PartofFT = 'Project', OriginalOT = 'description' WHERE RoleNo = 10.00
UPDATE Rolecopy SET PartofFT = 'Student', OriginalOT = 'Project' WHERE RoleNo = 15.0
```

0

Comment: You can use the `exec` statement: EXEC(@mySql)

Comment: i'd look into dynamic sql.  sure you can use exec(@sql), but that's open to any sql injection.

Comment: doesn't work, because of the quotes i think

Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Procedure SP_Grouping, Line 28
The name '' is not a valid identifier.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try using your first query to open a cursor, then within the loop execute the result string as dynamic SQL.

```
declare commands cursor for
SELECT 'UPDATE Rolecopy SET PartofFT = ''' + R2.PlayedbyOT + ''', OriginalOT = ''' + R.PlayedbyOT + ''' WHERE RoleNo = ' + CAST(R.RoleNo AS VARCHAR) + CHAR(13)
FROM Role R INNER JOIN Role R2
ON R.PartofFT = R2.PartofFT AND R.RoleNo <> R2.RoleNo
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT PG.RoleNo
    FROM V_PurposeGrouping PG
    WHERE R.PartofFT = PG.PartofFT
    AND R.RoleNo <> PG.RoleNo
)

declare @cmd varchar(max)

open commands
fetch next from commands into @cmd
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin
  exec(@cmd)
  fetch next from commands into @cmd
end

close commands
deallocate commands
```

Comment: i wonder if someone could come up witha  good recursive cte statement to combine with a dynamic sql statement to get this to work.  if i had the time i'd try it.

Comment: what i mean is you use a cte to generate the initial select statement, then using a recursive cte to append it all into a string, and then execute that.  if you did it right you could also set up the parameters in a different string and send that to the sp_executesql statement.  at least in theory it could work, i'd have to try it

Comment: @DForck42, I think I see what you're talking about and it should be doable.  I'd be curious to see if anything is gained by it... aside from a maintenance headache...

Comment: sure, but if done right then you don't have the chance of someone putting a string of sql code in the data and having it execute, like you do using exec(@sql)

Answer (score 4):

Try using this :

```
SELECT 'UPDATE Rolecopy SET PartofFT = ''' + R2.PlayedbyOT + ''', OriginalOT = ''' + R.PlayedbyOT + ''' WHERE RoleNo = ' + CAST(R.RoleNo AS VARCHAR) + CHAR(13)
FROM Role R INNER JOIN Role R2
ON R.PartofFT = R2.PartofFT AND R.RoleNo <> R2.RoleNo
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT PG.RoleNo
    FROM V_PurposeGrouping PG
    WHERE R.PartofFT = PG.PartofFT
    AND R.RoleNo <> PG.RoleNo
)
FOR XML PATH ('')
```

For which the result is going into one string column:

```
UPDATE Rolecopy SET PartofFT = 'Student', OriginalOT = 'Teacher' WHERE RoleNo = 5.00
UPDATE Rolecopy SET PartofFT = 'Project', OriginalOT = 'Teacher' WHERE RoleNo = 8.00
UPDATE Rolecopy SET PartofFT = 'Project', OriginalOT = 'description' WHERE RoleNo = 10.00
UPDATE Rolecopy SET PartofFT = 'Student', OriginalOT = 'Project' WHERE RoleNo = 15.0
```

All in the same column.