# Running SQL Query from a SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql, ssms

I have a table where I want to run a query that I get from a query.

[image]

What I want to do is return the name (checkbooks, clients, etc) and the results of the sql queries per each type. all within one query result so I can send that data out.  I have no clue where to start.

Comment: how do you access the db? EF?

Comment: yes EF or raw sql

Comment: This is such a bad idea, I have no clue where to start. If there is any chance to change approach, change it now. Otherwise, there is always `sys.sp_executesql`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using your first query to open a cursor, then within the loop execute the result string as dynamic SQL. I dont know what your tables or columns are called, but assuming table is called Table and column containing those Selects is Result, you could try something like:

```
declare commands cursor for 

select result from table

declare @cmd varchar(max)

open commands
fetch next from commands into @cmd
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin
  exec(@cmd)
  fetch next from commands into @cmd
end

close commands
deallocate commands
```

Inspired by this question:
[execute result of select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035286/execute-result-of-select-statement)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>This doesn't look like a good idea, unless there is no way for you to change this approach.</strike>

If you are using EF, after getting the row, you can execute the query in the query test field like this
context.MyEntity.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.MyEntity").ToList();

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql

You can do the same with different ORM, the idea is simple get the string in the field and pass it to the execute query.

FYI: Is saving SQL statements in a table for executing later a bad idea?
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/227922/is-saving-sql-statements-in-a-table-for-executing-later-a-bad-idea